# how to disable cas if I use web.xml configuration

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, struts, cas, jasig

I have problem to disable JASIG CAS SSO without touching web.xml. For now I configure cas like that [cas web.xml config](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/casc/configuring+the+jasig+cas+client+for+java+in+the+web.xml) . 
The best way it would be to somehow move all the configuration to external property file to disable it easy during development as I won't have access to CAS server once it will be implemented.
I tried to move configuration as a spring bean like here [bean definition for cas server](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Configuring+the+JA-SIG+CAS+Client+for+Java+using+Spring) . Unfortunately I kept getting errors about service/servername configuration even though I provided them all. Is there any good explanation of configuration cas externatly I will be very grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure another intercept filter before cas filter is invoked and then control it from there with a flag. If the flag is enabled, you can continue with the cas filter. If not enabled, you can decide to skip the cas flow and redirect it to your regular flow.

Comment: Can you show me the example how would it be implemented.

Comment: @lucaskos https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/